# Use Apply on a SeriesGroupBy Object where conditions are met

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame `df1`:

```
 df1.head() = 

           id      ret     eff
    1469  2300 -0.010879  4480.0
    328   2300 -0.000692 -4074.0
    1376  2300 -0.009551  4350.0
    2110  2300 -0.014013  5335.0
    849   2300 -0.286490 -9460.0
```

I would like to create a new column that contains the normalized values of the column `df1['eff']`.
In other words, I would like to group `df1['eff']`by `df1['id']`, look for the max value (`mx = df1['eff'].max()`) and the min value (`mn = df2['eff'].min()`), and divide in a pairwise fashion each value of the column `df1['eff']`by `mn`or `mx` depending if `df1['eff'] > 0` or  `df1['eff']< 0`.

The code that I have written is the following:

```
df1['normd'] = df1.groupby('id')['eff'].apply(lambda x: x/x.max() if x > 0 else x/x.min())
```

However python throws the following error:

```
*** ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(),
 a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Since `df1.groupby('id')['eff']` is a `SeriesGroupBy Object`, i decided to use `map()`. 
But again python throws the following error:

```
 *** AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'map' of 'SeriesGroupBy' ob
 jects, try using the 'apply' method
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is that it's not clear what you mean by `df1['eff'] > 0`, even in plain English. Are you saying that you know that all `'eff'` values within a group will have the same sign?

Comment: Then of course when you apply, `x` is a series so pandas doesn't know what to make of `x > 0`. I wouldn't either, hence my question ;)

Comment: I thought that `map()`was a pair-wise function. Therefore, by using `df1['eff']>0`I meant to pairwise analyse whether each value in the column `df1['eff']`is positive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use custom function `f`, where is possible easy add `print`. So `x` is `Series` and you need compare each group by [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). Output is `numpy array` and you need convert it to `Series`:

```
def f(x):
    #print (x)
    #print (x/x.max())
    #print (x/x.min())
    return pd.Series(np.where(x>0, x/x.max(), x/x.min()), index=x.index)


df1['normd'] = df1.groupby('id')['eff'].apply(f)
print (df1)
        id       ret     eff     normd
1469  2300 -0.010879  4480.0  0.839738
328   2300 -0.000692 -4074.0  0.430655
1376  2300 -0.009551  4350.0  0.815370
2110  2300 -0.014013  5335.0  1.000000
849   2300 -0.286490 -9460.0  1.000000
```

What is same as:

```
df1['normd'] = df1.groupby('id')['eff']
                  .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.where(x>0, 
                                                      x/x.max(), 
                                                      x/x.min()), index=x.index))
print (df1)
        id       ret     eff     normd
1469  2300 -0.010879  4480.0  0.839738
328   2300 -0.000692 -4074.0  0.430655
1376  2300 -0.009551  4350.0  0.815370
2110  2300 -0.014013  5335.0  1.000000
849   2300 -0.286490 -9460.0  1.000000
```